# How to load Touchgfx files to external flash

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx, stm32cubeide

I have W95Q64 flash memory and STM32F429 custom board. I want to load Touhgfx files to external flash memory. For this purpose, firstly I added below declarations into FLASH.id file as;

`SPIFLASH    (r)    : ORIGIN = 0x9000000,   LENGTH = 8M`

and

```
ExtFlashSection :
  {
    *(ExtFlashSection ExtFlashSection.*)
    *(.gnu.linkonce.r.*)
    . = ALIGN(0x4);
  } >SPIFLASH
  
  FontFlashSection :
  {
    *(FontFlashSection FontFlashSection.*)
    *(.gnu.linkonce.r.*)
    . = ALIGN(0x4);
  } >SPIFLASH
  
  TextFlashSection :
  {
    *(TextFlashSection TextFlashSection.*)
    *(.gnu.linkonce.r.*)
    . = ALIGN(0x4);
  } >SPIFLASH
```

after compilation in CubeIde, the memory is created as shown below;

[image]

My problem is that I dont know how to download all those files to my board. As far as I know, I need to use external loader in debugger section but there is no convenient option in the tab which is exactly match with my configuration.

[image]

it will be appreciated if someone explain what to do additionally and **explain all procedures step by step.**

Note: I include the [library](https://github.com/NimaLTD/w25qxx) and called W25qxx_Init() in the main block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no configuration that matches the memory you use, the MCU, and the pin connection, you need to write your own external flash loader which will be a .stldr file.
There is a video tutorial from ST:
https://github.com/vlcekji2/External-Loaders